# Why is "you cannot buy all what you like" wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

I got the following sentences from http://www.engvid.com/english-resource/50-common-grammar-mistakes-in-english-2/

> Wrong: You cannot buy all what you like!
>   Right: You cannot buy all that you like!

Why is the first one wrong? I do see the structure "you can do what you..." many times, e.g. "how to talk about what you want".

Comment: Please [search the site](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=all+what) before asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The part "that you like" is a relative clause. "That" is its relative pronoun. "What" is **not** a relative pronoun, therefore it can't introduce a relative clause.

Comment: Is this sentence 'how to talk about what you want' right

Answer (score 0):

It's because *that you like* is a relative clause, and *what* cannot introduce a relative clause in Standard English. In practice, this sentence would be more likely to occur as *You can't buy everything you like*.

Comment: Don't some regional variants of English allow 'what' to introduce relative clauses? (an example is exactly the first one above)

Comment: They do. That's why I specified Standard English.